# How to use JSObjectMakeDeferredPromise to call a function in JavaScript from Swift that returns a promise

Tags: ios, swift, promise, javascriptcore

I'd like to be able to call a function from a JSContext that returns a promise. It appears that JSObjectMakeDeferredPromise is the mechanism to do that but there's so little documentation that I'm unsure on how to do it.

Can anyone provide an example of calling a function in a JSContext that returns a promise?

Answer (score 0):

WebKit is an open-source project. I found an [issue](https://www.mail-archive.com/webkit-changes@lists.webkit.org/msg145028.html) related to that function. <strike>This function more likes to throw an exception for unhandled promise rejections.</strike>

<strike>So you can not use that function to return a promise. But</strike> JavaScriptCore supports Promise keyword. I run this script on macOS with Xcode 11.4.1. That works well.

```
const promiseA = new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    emulator.downloadWithHandler( (response) => {
        var isFinish = response["isFinish"];
        var isCancelled = response["isCancelled"];
        var date = response["date"];

        console.log("isFinish: " + isFinish);
        console.log("isCancelled: " + isCancelled);
        console.log("date: " + date);

        if (isFinish || isCancelled) {
            resolve(date);
        }
    });
});
```

The `emulator.downloadWithHandler` is a native callback that will return on background DispatchQueue at some point. If you want to use retrive that promise and keep it. Call `context.objectForKeyedSubscript("promiseA")` and wrapper it use `JSManagedValue`.

---

It not much useful to keep a reference for a `Promise`. More important is how to access the variable and function in the `JSContext`.

You can call JSContext's `evaluateScript(_:)`. That context will not deinit and could use if you retain the context after script returns. Get the object from context and then use the JSValue's `invokeMethod(_:withArguments:)` or `call(withArguments:)` could also work.

NSHipster have a great [article](https://nshipster.com/javascriptcore/) about that framework. You can take a reference for it.

---

After I check the document and the iOS 13+ new API. There are something could be confirmed. That is you can use `JSObjectMakeDeferredPromise` create `Promise` and this is the C way. For convenience, I create required function via the Swift way and export to C. So the answer is:

```swift
let context = JSContext()
var ref = context.jsGlobalContextRef
context.evaluateScript("function resolve(value) { console.log(value); };")
var resolve = context.objectForKeyedSubscript("resolve")?.jsValueRef
context.evaluateScript("function reject(reason) { console.log(reason); };")
var reject = context.objectForKeyedSubscript("reject")?.jsValueRef

var exception: JSValueRef?
var promise = JSObjectMakeDeferredPromise(ref, &resolve, &reject, &exception)

(lldb) po promise
▿ Optional<OpaquePointer>
  ▿ some : 0x000000010c74ae78
    - _rawValue : (Opaque Value)

(lldb) p promise
(JSObjectRef?) $R4 = 0x000000010c74ae78
```

I do not want to dive in more deep. That just means you can use JavaScriptCore with C interface. And `JSValue` has iOS 13+ new C style init method likes `.init(newPromiseIn:fromExecutor:)`. It looks like the same but I'm not pretty sure.

If you insist on using C API. This [article](https://karhm.com/javascriptcore_c_api/) may be helpful.

P.S.
The `console.log` method is a handmake native exporting log method.

Comment: It's still not clear to me how I would use this from a JSContext. For example suppose instead of `promiseA` being a constant it was a function. How would I invoke it in that scenario?

Comment: Sure. The promise you get here is will finish its jobs so that no much useful to keep a reference here. Your new question is how to access javascript functions in the context. I update my answer. Please check it.

Comment: The answer still doesn’t answer the question or provide an example of how to use JSMakeDeferredPromise.

Comment: @Centinul did you find a way to implement the promise(returned from JS) resolve, reject in Swift native code?

Answer (score 0):

`JSObjectMakeDeferredPromise` is low level function from C JavaScriptCore API that helps to create a JavaScript's Promise instance and managing it on the native side. The promise instance can be returned from a bridged native functions for use in JavaScript like asynchronous functions, for instance:

```swift
let context = JSContext()!

let helloWithTimeout: @convention(block) (Double) -> JSValue? = { timeout in
    var resolveRef: JSValueRef?
    var rejectRef: JSValueRef?
    let promiseRef = JSObjectMakeDeferredPromise(context.jsGlobalContextRef, &resolveRef, &rejectRef, nil);
    let resolve = JSValue(jsValueRef: resolveRef, in: context)
    let promise = JSValue(jsValueRef: promiseRef, in: context)
    
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: timeout / 1000, repeats: false) { timer in
        resolve?.call(withArguments: ["Hello Promise!"])
    }
    
    return promise
}
context.setObject(helloWithTimeout, forKeyedSubscript: "helloWithTimeout" as NSString)

let script =
"""
helloWithTimeout(300)
.then (data => {
    console.log(data) // Prints: Hello Promise!
})
"""
context.evaluateScript(script)
```

But it's better to use `JSValue.init(newPromiseIn:fromExecutor:)` that provides a convenient way to work with promises without any additional low-level code:

```swift
let helloWithTimeout: @convention(block) (Double) -> JSValue? = { timeout in
    JSValue(newPromiseIn: context) { resolve, reject in
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: timeout / 1000, repeats: false) { timer in
            resolve?.call(withArguments: ["Hello Promise!"])
        }
    }
}
```